# What data types does a SharedObject support?

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

I know it is a simple matter to store Strings and Numbers with a SharedObject, and I am also familiar with this sort of thing:

```
var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("userData");
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.prop = "value";
sharedObject.data.userobj= obj;
sharedObject.flush();
```

However, I am attempting to store an object of the class GameStage, a class I have defined to hold data about stages in my game. This type of thing doesn't seem to be working:

```
var sharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("userData");
var stageOne:GameStage = new GameStage();
stageOne.highScore = 99999;
sharedObject.data.stageOne = stageOne;
sharedObject.flush();
```

This code doesn't throw an error, but when I try to retrieve the stage data later, like so:

```
stageOne = sharedObject.data.stageOne;
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@3d220629 to GameStage.
```

I guess my question is: exactly what sort of data types can be stored in a SharedObject? Everywhere I've looked online has answered that question with "anything that can be used in Flash", which isn't very descriptive – obviously my GameStage class works in Flash too. Is there something about retrieving data from the SharedObject that I'm not aware of?

My prediction is that I will not be able to store my stage data this way. If that is the case, could anyone suggest an alternative method to saving the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store any object in a [SharedObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=lsos_3.html), but you need to register the class first:

> You can store typed ActionScript
>   instances in shared objects. You do
>   this by calling the
>   flash.net.registerClassAlias() method
>   to register the class. If you create
>   an instance of your class and store it
>   in the data member of your shared
>   object and later read the object out,
>   you will get a typed instance. By
>   default, the SharedObject
>   objectEncoding property supports AMF3
>   encoding, and unpacks your stored
>   instance from the SharedObject object;
>   the stored instance retains the same
>   type you specified when you called the
>   registerClassAlias() method.

One caveat is that storing object graphs can sometimes lead to storage issues. There is a limit to how much you can store in SharedObject before it notifies the user and asks for permission to store more. This threshold is 100k by default, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Flex Builder SDK or Flex Builder you can also use the [RemoteClass] metatag which will automatically register the class and make it serializable.